# Function syntax in legacy javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, dom-events

I am working on an old ASP.NET code base that has functions defined inside of a `<script language="javascript">` block in an aspx file. The functions are defined like so

```
function document.onmouseover() {
  // blah blah
}
```

I can't find any documentation on this syntax online. Was this ever a standard? 
Or is this just a grossly wrong way of writing

```
document.onmouseover = function() {
  // blah blah
}
```

The code raises an exception when I run set it up and run it on my machine under Visual Studio, but it runs fine unmodified on an IIS server in production somewhere. I have no idea how. The exception I get locally is a `Syntax Error` as one would expect.

In summation, what is likely to break if I change the function definitions from the first type to the second type?

I would also like to add that this particular codebase was and is only meant to run on Internet Explorer. It started with IE6 and has now been upgraded from IE 8 or 9.

Comment: Share the error stacktrace. It's not good to attached event listener on `document` as it's firing for every mouse hover instead attached on the particular element inside.

Comment: My question is only about the function definition syntax used. The first one has a dot in the function title. That's where my error is. And I know that it's not good practice to add an event listener directly to the document object, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's just wrong. It's impossible to answer however if anything might break by fixing it. Sometimes making something work that was previously broken exposes other problems, by triggering code that didn't fire before, for example. However I'd expect the code to work better if you fixed it. As everyone knows IE6 does some weird s#$%t, so maybe that syntax is OK in IE6. I don't ever want to see its face again, so I'm not going to test it... ;)

Comment: I can't find it in any standard either. I had to be sure. Stuff like `window.createPopup` can sneak up on ya. I had no idea that was a thing until I saw this codebase. I definitely feel you on the never wanting to see its face thing.